# Webdriver.io Comparator Operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webdriver-io

I am trying to ensure that the number of elements that are appearing on a webpage is greater than zero. I am unaware of a way to assert that the elements I need are correctly populating. Below is what I have so far, but it is erring on the last line (i.e. `assert.equal(fieldsButtonList, "less than zero");`

```
const assert = require("assert");
import header from "../pages/header.page";

describe("View Report", () => {
  it("Only data fields that were selected, will display in the result’s column", () => {
    browser.url(""); // Navigate to the FDA app
    browser.maximizeWindow(); // ensure that the window is maximized so that everything can be viewed
    header.searchAndVisualizeHeader.click(); // Select the "Search & Visualize" tab
    const searchTitle = $("h1").getText();
    assert(searchTitle, "Show");
  });

  it("There should be buttons", () => {
    assert.equal(browser.$$(".data-source").length, 4);
    const ndcButton = $(
      '//*[@id="data-sidebar-item-0"]/div/div/div/div[2]/button'
    );
    ndcButton.click();
  });

  it("There should be fields", () => {
    const fieldsButton = browser.$('//*[@id="data-sidebar-item-1-heading"]');
    fieldsButton.click();
    const fieldsButtonList = () => {
      if (browser.$$(".data-field").length > 0) {
        return "greater than zero";
      } else {
        return "less than zero";
      }
    };
    //assert.equal(fieldsButtonList, "less than zero");
  });
});
```

The error that I am getting is as follows (running in latest Chrome Version 77.0.3865.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)):

```
[0-0] 2019-10-18T13:15:58.821Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("xpath", "//*[@id="data-sidebar-item-1-heading"]")
[0-0] 2019-10-18T13:15:58.821Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/d3813ab85ffd49ae3f3ba4c4b2df033f/element
[0-0] 2019-10-18T13:15:58.821Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'xpath',
  value: '//*[@id="data-sidebar-item-1-heading"]' }
[0-0] 2019-10-18T13:15:58.842Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { 'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '885111a2-8a1e-47df-ba60-ce764f56e58e' }
[0-0] 2019-10-18T13:15:58.846Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementClick("885111a2-8a1e-47df-ba60-ce764f56e58e")
[0-0] 2019-10-18T13:15:58.846Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/d3813ab85ffd49ae3f3ba4c4b2df033f/element/885111a2-8a1e-47df-ba60-ce764f56e58e/click
[0-0] AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION] in "View Report Fields should appear"
[Function: fieldsButtonList] == 'less than zero'
```

Comment: Hi @Joe, Could you please add what is the error you are getting.

Comment: @NaveenThiyagarajan I added the specific set of messages relating to that test. It just says `ERR_ASSERTION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the error:
`[Function: fieldsButtonList] == 'less than zero'` that is because the function reference is tried to compare against the value `less than zero`.

Issue is you are not calling the function at the line `assert.equal(fieldsButtonList, "less than zero");`.

You are still creating a reference to it.

Please replace the line of code as:
`assert.equal(fieldsButtonList(), "less than zero");`

Let us know this works.

Thanks,
Naveen